# How to Register Bean with SimpleRegistry using Camel 3

Tags: apache-camel

I'm updating an older Camel 2 application to Camel 3. I'm having issues with the following block of code:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
DataSource dataSource = setupDataSource(url);

SimpleRegistry reg = new SimpleRegistry();
reg.put("myDataSource", dataSource);

CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(reg);
```

In particular, the SimpleRegistry's put method is expecting a Map and not a Datasource:

```
argument mismatch; javax.activation.DataSource cannot be converted to java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,java.lang.Object>)
```

Can you recommend a fix for it? I have looked in the newer org.apache.camel.main.Main class but couldn't find a way to create a Camel Context from a SimpleRegistry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`bind`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.camel/camel-support/3.2.0/org/apache/camel/support/SimpleRegistry.html#bind-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-) method instead of `put`.

See [Apache Camel 2.x to 3.0 migration guide](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/camel-3-migration-guide.html):

> The class `SimpleRegistry` is moved from `org.apache.camel.impl` to `org.apache.camel.support`. Also you should favour using the `org.apache.camel.support.DefaultRegistry` instead. **Also you should use the `bind` operation instead of `put` to add entries to the `SimpleRegistry` or `DefaultRegistry`**.